# Perl program with regular expressions and comments exhibiting weird behaviour

Tags: regex, perl

I'v been playing around with Perl for a while for testing the examples in *Mastering Regular Expressions* by *Jeffrey E.F.Friedl* (Third edition). I've stumbled upon a really weird behavior with respect to Perl comments. Given below is the program that the author uses for "HTMLizing" text in a file.

```
undef $/;   # Enter file slurp mode.
$text=<>;   # Slurp up the first file given on the command line.

# Make characters safe.
$text =~ s{&}{&amp;}g;
$text =~ s{<}{&lt;}g;
$text =~ s{>}{&gt;}g;


# Add paragraph tags.
$text =~ s{^\s*$}{<p>}mg;

# Turn email addresses into links.
$text =~ s {
    \b
    (\w[-.\w]*
    \@
    [-a-z0-9]+(\.[-a-z0-9]+)*\.(com|edu|info)
    )
    \b
    }{<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>}gix;

print $text;
```

When I attempt to run this program using `perl htmlizer.pl input.txt`, I get the error below.

```
Backslash found where operator expected at htmlizer.pl line 17, near ")
        \"
        (Missing operator before \?)
syntax error at htmlizer.pl line 13, near "w["
Unmatched right curly bracket at htmlizer.pl line 18, at end of line
Search pattern not terminated at htmlizer.pl line 18.
```

Here's where it gets totally weird. If I remove the `# Turn email addresses into links.` comment, the program executes fine! I'm surprised as to why should the addition of a comment affect the execution of the program.

Any clues? I'm using Perl v5.14.2

Comment: Executes fine here (Perl 5.16.3 on Windows). Upgrade? Might want to add `use strict;` but that shouldn't influence the odd error. BTW, `input.txt` is a bit misleading, should be `input.html`, no?

Comment: Hello Dan, I'm not sure what `use strict;` does - this is my first tryst with Perl. I would expect the books examples to work as-is, since the author explicitly mentions that the examples have been tested with Perl v5.8. About the file name, the program accepts a simple text file and outputs the corresponding html, but that's an argument for another day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get this exact error if I remove the newline after your comment (so the `$text =~ s {` is commented out).

Somehow, whatever you are seeing as a newline after that comment isn't being treated as such by perl.  What editor are you using?  If necessary, dump out your program with:

```
perl -wne'use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=$Data::Dumper::Terse=1; print Dumper $_' htmlizer.pl
```

and see what it shows at the end of that line.

Comment: It was as you suspected. See my answer above.

Comment: I'm using Padre for editing the Perl script(s). But I guess Notepad++ is a safer option :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, when I added the comment and hit the Return key, the CR control character was getting added, but not the LF character. This was confusing the Perl interpreter. Adding the LF character makes the program execute fine.

[image]